# Angularjs ui-router abstract state with resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to make an abstract state with ui-router that needs to resolve data? I need to load the top half of a page with profile info, and then have a sub-nav that loads other details at the bottom of the page. The idea is that the abstract state would load the profile info every time regardless of which child state I am on. It doesn't seem to work.

Example:

```
.state('app.profile', {
    abstract: true,
    url: 'user/:username',
    views: {
        content: {
            templateUrl: 'views/frontend/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            resolve: {
                data: ['$stateParams', 'ProfileService', function ($stateParams, ProfileService) {
                    var username = $stateParams.username;
                    return ProfileService.getProfile(username);
                }]
            }
        }
    }
})
.state('app.profile.something', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        profile: {
            templateUrl: 'views/frontend/profile.something.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            resolve: {
                data: ['$stateParams', 'ProfileService', function ($stateParams, ProfileService) {
                    var username = $stateParams.username;
                    return ProfileService.getProfileSomething(username);
                }]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Add the url to child state and empty the url property to parent state. then try

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow you.

Comment: That doesn't work. The $stateParams.username ends up undefined on the abstract state.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution here is to distinguish the names of the resolved data. Check this answer:

- [angular ui-route state parent and resolve (nested resolves)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24496321/1679310)

And its  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4E1Jy7XCvLRbOSu0muvL?p=preview)

So in our case we would need this change in parent

```
resolve: {
    dataParent: ['$stateParams', 'ProfileService', function ($stateParams, ProfileService) {
        var username = $stateParams.username;
        return ProfileService.getProfile(username);
    }]
}
```

and this in child

```
resolve: {
    dataChild: ['$stateParams', 'ProfileService', function ($stateParams, ProfileService) {
        var username = $stateParams.username;
        return ProfileService.getProfileSomething(username);
    }]
}
```

so, instead of working with resolve : { data: ... } in parent and child we would have these:

```
// parent state
resolve : { dataParent: ... } 
// child state
resolve : { dataChild: ... }
```

One [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4E1Jy7XCvLRbOSu0muvL?p=preview) should be better than other words...

Comment: It looks like I would have to create seperate controllers as well since I only want to inject the data that I am grabbing, correct?

Comment: I would say, different controllers for different states is good practice. Mostly if parent should handle different stuff than child... Does it help
?

Comment: Great to see that! ;) Enjoy amazing UI-Router ;)