# when using ui-router resolve, how do I access the resolved data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following routes:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("base",
    {
        url: "",
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
            aService: "aService",
            dataNeeded: function(aService) {
            return aService.getDataMethod().$promise;
            }
        },
        template: "<ui-view/>",
    });


$stateProvider
    .state("base.main",
    {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: coreConfig.path() + "/modules/content/content.tmpl.html",
        controller: "aController",
        controllerAs: "aCtrl",
        data: { requiresLogin: true }
    });
```

I'm using an abstract route to resolve data required in the child `'base.main'` route.

and in my app.js file I have

```
angular.module("aModule", ["CoreModule"])
    .controller({ "aController": require("./modules/content/aController.controller.js") });
```

I have my controller:

```
 module.exports = ["aService", "dataNeeded", aController];

    function aController(aService, dataNeeded) {
        var test = dataNeeded; //value is undefined
    }
```

How do I access the `'dataNeeded'` loaded in the abstract route from within the `'base.main' controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this Q & A

[angular-ui-router with requirejs, lazy loading of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22627806/1679310)

I created [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GPvFo6wOylZcmvU3eXf?p=preview), which is able to load controller with *RequireJS* and inject state **`resolve`** - from Parent or from the Child itself

This would be the state defintion:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("base",
  {
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
        dataNeeded: function(aService) {
          return aService.getDataMethod()
            .then(function(response){ return response.data }); //.$promise;
        }
    },
    template: "<ui-view/>",

  });

$stateProvider
  .state("base.other", {
    url: "/other",
    template: "<div>The message from ctrl: {{message}}" +
    "<br>and someResolved: <b>{{someResolved}}<b>" +
    "<br> and dataNeeded: <pre>{{dataNeeded | json}}</pre>" +
    "</div>",
    controller: "OtherCtrl", 
    resolve: {
      someResolved: function() { return "This is resolved value for key 'someResolved'" },
      loadOtherCtrl: ["$q", function($q) { 
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        require(["OtherCtrl"], function() { deferred.resolve(); });
        return deferred.promise;
      }],
    },
  });
```

For more details read [complete explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754025/1679310)...

And this is the controller for RequireJS:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    // the Default Controller
    // is added into the 'app' module
    // lazily, and only once
    app_cached_providers
      .$controllerProvider
      .register('OtherCtrl',['$scope', 'dataNeeded', 'aService', 'someResolved', 
        function ($scope, dataNeeded, aService, someResolved) {
          $scope.message = "OtherCtrl";
          $scope.someResolved = someResolved;
          $scope.dataNeeded = dataNeeded;
          console.log(dataNeeded)
          console.log(aService)
          console.log(someResolved)
    }]);

});
```

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GPvFo6wOylZcmvU3eXf?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

Every child state can ask for resloved stuff from its parent(s), so this would work

```
.controller('aController', ['$scope', 'dataNeeded', 
   function ($scope, dataNeeded) { 
     ...
}])
```

Check this related Q & A:

[Angularjs ui-router abstract state with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27168835/1679310)

And its [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4E1Jy7XCvLRbOSu0muvL?p=preview)

**EXTEND**

There is [another working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9QZLrdRbmPuzdrF9cKwF?p=preview) related to our scenario:

States:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("base", {
      url: "",
      abstract: true,
      resolve: {
        aService: "aService",
        dataNeeded: function(aService) {
          return aService.getDataMethod(); //.$promise;
        }
      },
      template: "<ui-view/>",
    });

$stateProvider
    .state("base.main", {
      url: "/main",
      //templateUrl: coreConfig.path() + "/modules/content/content.tmpl.html",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',
      controller: "aController",
      controllerAs: "aCtrl",
      data: {
        requiresLogin: true
      }
    });
  }
])
```

Controller and service:

```
.controller('aController', ['$scope', 'dataNeeded', 'aService',
    function($scope, dataNeeded, aService) {
      $scope.dataNeeded = dataNeeded;
      $scope.aService = aService;
    }
])
.factory('aService', function() {
    return {
      getDataMethod: function() {
        return { name:  "abc", id : 1 }
      }
    }
})
```

And a template which will render both **`'dataNeeded', 'aService'`** :

```
<h5>aService</h5>
  <b>{{aService}}</b>
<h5>dataNeeded</h5>
  <pre>{{dataNeeded | json}}</pre>
```

The example in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9QZLrdRbmPuzdrF9cKwF?p=preview)

MORE EXTEND

Another, [more extended example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5vpUaJ2jqSEmsEH5n1TO?p=preview) could be loading data.json:

```
{ "name":  "def", "id" : 22 }
```

The servcie would then be

```
.factory('aService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      getDataMethod: function() {
        return $http.get("data.json");
      }
    }
}])
```

And parent abstract resolve:

```
  resolve: {
    aService: "aService",
    dataNeeded: function(aService) {
      return aService.getDataMethod()
        .then(function(response){ return response.data }); //.$promise;
    }
  },
```

Check that [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/5vpUaJ2jqSEmsEH5n1TO?p=preview)

Comment: I thought I could access the data as you have indicated.  However, the data is not injected as expected.  See my edit to the question.

Comment: I've taken your example code, and created working plunker showin that all in action. The only change is, that I have no idea what should be the `aService.getDataMethod().$promise;` so in that case I just decided to use `aService.getDataMethod()`

Comment: And do you know what, I decided to even show you how to consume return server request... check the extended answer part and its special working example

Comment: These are great examples.  However, i think the issue I'm having is related to how my controllers are created using require.js

Comment: I am doing my best to assist you and you now reveal that your scenario is different ... well ...

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js

```
  resolve:{
      aService: "aService",
      dataNeeded: function(aService) {
        return aService.getDataMethod().$promise;
      }
   },
```

In your controller :

```
app.controller('ServiceController', [
    'aService',
    'dataNeeded',
    function(aService, dataNeeded ) {
   ...
}];
```

Now, you access 'aService' and the 'dataNeeded' loaded inside your controller 'ServiceController'.

Comment: I thought I could access the data as you have indicated.  However, the data is not injected as expected.  See my edit to the question.