# What is the best way to resolve data before loading view and controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I've a page with Navbar and Sidebar that remains common across most of the pages and hence I load all data related to LoggedInUser in NavbarController.

This data ($scope.loggedInUser) is used in other Controllers (child controller) as well. Since call to get User data is async, many times, child controller tries to access data before it is returned from the server.

What is the best way to ensure, all promises of parent controller are resolved before child controller starts it's work?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626919/when-using-ui-router-resolve-how-do-i-access-the-resolved-data

Comment: What if I'm using ng-route instead of ui-router?

Comment: No problem for this . you can use `resolve` for `ng-route`

Comment: That means, I will end up making same request multiple times. Once for parent controller (Navbar) and then for individual child controllers.

Comment: when using `resolve` the view will not render until `resolve` not completed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `resolve` from $stateProvider. This function ensures that all the promises are resolved before loading a new state.

Comment: What if I'm using ng-route instead of ui-router?

Comment: It has the same functionality: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Answer (score 0):

A resolve is a property you can attach to a route in both ngRoute and the more robust UI router. A resolve contains one or more promises that must resolve successfully before the route will change. This means you can wait for data to become available before showing a view, and simplify the initialization of the model inside a controller because the initial data is given to the controller instead of the controller needing to go out and fetch the data.

```
$routeProvider
.when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "newsView.html",
    controller: "newsController",
    resolve: {
        message: function(messageService){
            return messageService.getMessage();
    }
}

})
```

in controller

```
app.controller("newsController", function (message) {
$scope.message = message;
```

});

Hope this will help you