# How are UI-Router's resolve function arguments resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I obviously have missed something from UI-Router and/or angular's documentations so, although I will sound stupid, here it is:

In http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider we have an example resolve function:

```
resolve: {
    myResolve1:
      function($http, $stateParams) {
        return $http.get("/api/foos/"+$stateParams.fooID);
      }
    }
```

I understand that its return value will be injected into the controller under the name "myResolve1".

What is less clear to me is where the values for the function parameters **"$http"** and **"$stateParams"** are coming from. So, where did the caller find the values to give to this function ?

Comment: They're injected through Angular's dependency injection system, the same way you would with a controller function.

Comment: See $injector.invoke here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Your resolve methods are invoked with this method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good point, and as discussed for example here

#### [Angularjs ui-router abstract state with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27168835/1679310)

we should use the IoC oriented notation

```
resolve: {
    dataParent: ['$stateParams', 'ProfileService', function ($stateParams, ProfileService) {
        var username = $stateParams.username;
        return ProfileService.getProfile(username);
    }]
}
```

The biggest benefit(s) is ... it will work even with minification applied. But mostly, it is now really clearly stated:

> there is an array with all required dependency names - and the resolve function as a last argument

Comment: IoC oriented notation ?

Comment: Absolutely! That is the point.. 1) well your code, will work as well... just until it is minified. Then your names will become `function(a,b)` and these 'a' and 'b' will not be registered... 2) the Array (the IoC notation) with names and last function will avoid that scenario

Comment: I am sorry but I am curious where this term "IoC oriented notation" comes from.

Comment: haha: Inversion of Control (IoC) is a design pattern that addresses a component’s dependency resolution, configuration and lifecycle. IoC is best understood through the Hollywood Principle: “Dont’s call us, we’ll call you”.

Comment: I see please, check this [Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation). There is all about AngularJS IoC and mostly about notation we should use. If we do not, and code is minified, angular tries to guess the service names by the variable names... but that is a dirty way, I'd say...

Comment: @mathieu International Olympic Committee. Programming in Angular will soon be an Olympic event. Just kidding...[Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). It's a fancy way of referring to dependency injection.

Comment: that is most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: /me 's just had one of these eureka moments

Answer (score 0):

You can inject anything that you would normally inject into your controller into a resolve function including other resolves. You need to be careful with this because if you are chaining resolves it will take longer for the state to navigate completely therefore rendering your view slower. An example of chaining resolves would look like this.

```
resolve: {
    loggedIn: function(auth){ return  auth.requireLoggedIn()},
    user: function(loggedIn, auth){return auth.resolveUser()}
}
```

auth is a service that is part of my angular application and as you can see loggedIn is a resolve that needs to resolve before it can be used to load your user. You could then inject both of those into your controller.

You can put any Angular service, factory, filter or resolve in there.. And I'm sure I'm missing some other core things you can add as well but that's generally what I inject into a resolve. So to answer your question they just come from your Angular application.